# vim-foreplay is really slow with Ruby 1.9 but fast with Ruby 1.8 on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, vim, clojure

I noticed that [vim-foreplay](https://github.com/tpope/vim-foreplay) on Windows is really slow when doing things that involve sending code to nrepl (a Java process for those that don't know) and I think it does that with Ruby. I tried it with [Vim without Cream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/) 7.3.762 which uses Ruby 1.9.3, and with Vim installed from the official Vim Windows installer also with ruby 1.9.3 (I could not get this version to work with Ruby 1.8, I don't know how that works and if it's even supposed to work). Both of them were very slow together vim-foreplay, sending something to be evaluated took about 1 second. But Vim without Cream 7.3.289 that is built for Ruby 1.8 is much, much faster; evaluating is instant. How come?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, opening a connection to `localhost` with `TCPSocket.open()` in Ruby 1.9.3-p362 on Windows is slow, but to `127.0.0.1` is a lot faster.

Thanks to https://github.com/tpope for helping me find this out.